# Error compiling Cython file in buildozer

Tags: python, cython, buildozer, cythonize, pyjnius

I have built an android app using kivy and while I was compiling it to build an apk using buildozer, the following error popped up;

```
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running python.host -c import sys; print(sys.path)
           working: ['', '/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-instal[INFO]:    Trying first build of pyjnius to get cython files: this is expected to fail
[INFO]:    -> running python.host setup.py build_ext -v
('cwd is', '/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius')               
           working:  #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilatiException in thread background thread for pid 3379:   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2455, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2153, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
/usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -I/home/himanshu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -isysroot /home/himanshu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -I/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -I/home/himanshu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -isysroot /home/himanshu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -I/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python2.7 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python2.7 -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
error: command '/usr/bin/ccache' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    pyjnius first build failed (as expected)
[INFO]:    Running cython where appropriate
[INFO]:    Cythonize jnius/jnius.pyx
[INFO]:    -> running cython ./jnius/jnius.pyx
()                                                                                                                                                   
           working:             for interface in getattr(value, '__javainterfaces__', []):     Exception in thread background thread for pid 3389:   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2455, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2153, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/local/bin/cython ./jnius/jnius.pyx

  STDOUT:

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            if jcs is not None:
                obj = jcs.j_cls

        if NULL == obj:
            for interface in getattr(value, '__javainterfaces__', []):
                obj = j_env[0].FindClass(j_env, str_for_c(interface))
                                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi:133:57: Obtaining 'char *' from temporary Python value


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 573, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 928, in build_arch
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 963, in build_cython_components
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1008, in cythonize_build
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 999, in cythonize_file
  File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/himanshu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/local/bin/cython ./jnius/jnius.pyx

  STDOUT:

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            if jcs is not None:
                obj = jcs.j_cls

        if NULL == obj:
            for interface in getattr(value, '__javainterfaces__', []):
                obj = j_env[0].FindClass(j_env, str_for_c(interface))
                                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi:133:57: Obtaining 'char *' from temporary Python value


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/himanshu/helplineapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I know that there is some issue with latest version of cython and so I downgraded to cython==0.20 but no luck, still the same error. I have already compiled two more programs using buildozer by downgrading cython but now, in this case, I don't know whats happening. Some other answers here say that raising log level 2 in buildozer.spec file will clarify the details of the error but I am new to buildozer. I don't know how to do that.

Also, this process takes too long while it downloads SDK tools and so I am limited with resources. I request humbly to please help me getting rid of this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously there is an error in the cython code, but without seeing the cython code we cannot say how to fix. Is there information available with which cython version it is supposed to be build?

Answer (score 1):

I had something very similar in regards to cython versions. I only ever managed to get my buildozer to work with cython 0.23. It took many hours and many reinstalls to figure that out...

Perhaps give cython 0.23 a try. I can personally confirm that it works with buildozer 0.34.dev0.